# Does changing the process template from Agile to CMMI in my AzureDevOps project impact the pipelines, test suites, etc.?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to change the process in my project and I cannot find anything online on the impact this change has on the pipelines, test suites, etc. Would really appreciate some input from someone more experienced than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration to CMMI is not supported now. You will get the following error:

[image]

Basically, you should not have issues with test cases, test plans, because all process templates contain them. Pipelines and source code are not a part of process templates.

Comment: I will be able to overcome that error by creating a work item called user story for a brief moment. I will then change the User Stories to Requirements and remove the newly created item. This aspect was the least of my worries. 

I was more worried about the things you say I won't have issues with. Thank you for the help!